# Code Igniter with nginx giving 404 error for nested applications

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

Our third party provider has created a codeigniter site within codeigniter site.

This means below:

1 : we have standard application folder with CI case folder.

2 : Inside that we have admin folder which is copy of CI base folder. Think about it as someone copying codeigniter within code igniter by renaming CI as 'admin'.

Our nginx.conf is as below:

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1035;
pid /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
        worker_connections 1024;
        multi_accept on;
        use kqueue;
}

http {

        include mime.types;

        server{
                listen 80;
               server_name localhost ;

                access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.access.log  ;
                error_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/default.error.log  ;

                #root /Users/rishi/appiness/rishijfh;
                root /Users/rishi/appiness/JobsForHer-PHP;

                index index.php index.html;

                location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?args;
                }

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        include fastcgi.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                }




}
```

The CI/application folder's .htaccess file have below content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The CI/admin/application folder's .htaccess file have below content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine on
       RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

CI/application works fine but CI/admin/aplication throws 404 error.

I have search alot and tried below
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-solve-CodeIgniters-404-not-found-error
http://www.arifulhaque.com/codeigniter-htaccess-and-index-php-issues-solution/

None of the solutions working for us. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the "outer" CI is trying to lookup the admin as a controller, instead of the browser diving into the folder.

Try these rewrite conditions in the "outer" CI (not in application folder but the root) right before the actual rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

It should then look something like this (copied mine in here):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
    RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```